# Arrow Number Boxes

Tags: mathematics, visual

I came across this riddle in [The Big Book of Brain Games by Ivan Moscovich](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0761134662) (Riddle #12)

the book does provide the solution, but I've got no clue how to go about solving it.

If you do own this book, I suggest you open it right now and try to solve the riddle yourself (but don't look at the answers!); if not, here's the riddle:

> The object of this sort of riddle is to place arrows in the boxes according to the following rules:
>   
>   The arrows must point in one of the eight main compass directions (north, south, east, west, northeast, southeast, northwest, and southwest); the number of arrows pointing to each number in the outer boxes must equal the value of that number; and each box must have an arrow in it. The sample shown (upper right) is a flawed attempt at a solution, since since no arrow can be placed on the blank square within the rules of the game, and one of the outer squares has no arrow pointing at it.
>   
>   can you find complete solutions for the for the arrow number boxes of order 4 (upper left), order 5 (lower left), and order 6 (lower right)?
>   [image: Photo]

So, to sum it up, you need to: 
1. give the solution for the original riddle 
2. explain the method for solving the riddle 
3. (not necessary but much appreciated) provide the background for this riddle; i.e: who created it, what mathematical concept it is based on, etc.

Comment: I think explaining the method of solving this puzzle will be harder than solving it.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir That's true, but I always hope that the solution can be obtained by thinking instead of brute-forcing.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I'm not looking for the solution though, I'm looking for the method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to the first one (I think. I tried to double check, but I may have missed something)

> [image: Solution to 4x4]

My methodology is probably not optimal, but it went roughly

> Start with a "corner direction." Fit it into as many spots as you can to take care of edge pieces.

I then

> Looked at which edge had the least open spaces remaining on it. In this scenario, I did all the down right arrows, then did the right facing arrows.

This solved

> The whole right hand side, more or less. I added the down arrow to take care of the bottom of the 4th column, as well.

I then added

> all the down left arrows. After that, there weren't very many spots left, and I put pieces where they fit.

I'll see if I can apply the same/similar logic to the 5x5 (and eventually the 6x6 maybe) to see if I'm able to better nail down my thought process.

EDIT:

5x5 --

> [image: 5x5]

I have come to the conclusion that solving these is VERY non-single-answer-y. The methodology that I used to solve this one was

> Draw the possible arrows on each square. After that, find the squares with the fewest possible arrows, and then pick the one that points to a higher number, and draw it in.

After that I

> Eliminated any arrows for squares that were completely filled in, and started the process again for the squares with remaining arrows

While prioritizing

> Filling out arrows in squares with only one option remaining immediately.

I found multiple possible answers towards the end.

Comment: Good job. I have a different solution. Given how easy it was to find by just going through adding arrows sequentially (eliminating impossible directions as I went) suggests that there are many possible solutions to this. Unsurprisingly, since the arrows don't really interact with each other.

Comment: Yeah, on looking at the 5x5, I think there is a significant number of possible solutions to the puzzles. I don't think it's necessarily limited to a single solution.

Comment: @phroureo yup, next to the answers given in the book, the author points out that the given solution is "one of the many possible solutions".

Comment: Also, about your method for the 5x5: I used the exact same method you used, but I found that it is unapplicable for the 6x6 one, either that or I made a mistake